# Axios get request not returning data in laravel + vue

Tags: php, vue.js, axios, vuejs3, laravel-10

I have an invoice page which shows the invoice rows from database using vue. I use laravel 10 with vue 3 composition api. I requested the data with axios and save them in vue ref but the data is undefined when I logged the response

Here is the console.log:
[image: console log]
template for the invoices:

```
<div class="table--items" v-for="invoice in invoices" :key="invoice.id" v-if="invoices">
    <a href="#" class="table--items--transactionId">#{{invoice.id}}</a>
    <p>{{invoice.date}}</p>
    <p>#{{invoice.number}}</p>
    <p>{{invoice.customer_id}}</p>
    <p>{{invoice.due_date}}</p>
    <p> $ {{invoice.total}}</p>
 </div>
 <div class="table--items" v-else>
     <p>INVOICES NOT FOUND</p>
 </div>
```

Script in index.vue:

```
<script setup>
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';

let invoices = ref([])
// lifecycle hook - when component mounts
onMounted(async () => {
    getInvoices()
})
const getInvoices = async () => {
    let response = await axios.get("/api/getInvoices")
    // invoices.value = response.data.invoices        
    console.log(response.data.invoices)
}
```

InvoiceController:

```
public function getInvoices(){
    $invoices = Invoice::all();
    return response()->json([
        'invoices' => $invoices
    ],200);
}
```

Api.php:

```
Route::get('/api/getInvoices',[InvoiceController::class, 'getInvoices']);
```

Web.php:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/{pathMatch}', function (){
    return view('welcome');
})->where('pathMatch','.*');
```

Default bootstrap.js:

```
import axios from 'axios';
window.axios = axios;    
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

Comment: If you check the Network tab of the browser's developer console, do you see a proper response from the api?

Comment: @aynber the getInvoices is running with a status 200, xhr type, in the network tab

Comment: @aynber It had a waiting time for the server response about 245.10ms and then said content downloaded 3.94ms

Comment: Click on the request, and look at the Response tab. What does that show?

Comment: I see a html page in the response tab. The welcome.blade.php one where I mounted the vue app

Comment: Okay, so it's hitting your web.php before it hits your api.php, and hitting that catchall route (pathMatch). Go into your RouteServiceProvider, and make sure that the `api` directives are before the `web` directives.

Comment: Yes, `Route::middleware('api')` is before the web one in the RouteServiceProvider if that is what you mean.

Comment: You should use axios.post('/api/start').then((response) => {console.log(response.data.invoices)))
only when async ended